Why is there more than one version of Luffy reuniting with Sabo?
In episode 663 of One Piece, the version I see almost exclusively now has Luffy recognising Sabo once he removes his hat. But, in the (I think) original version, Sabo and Luffy have a conversation which includes Sabo asking if Luffy thinks he wouldn't be able to recognise his brother because he's in disguise.
Why does the variation exist, and is the entire episode of the 'original' still available somewhere?
YouTube videos of the version I see now and the version I am referring to.

The scene that cuts to the exterior right after Luffy's expression of shock is from One Piece episode 663 "Luffy Astonished - The Man Who Inherits Ace's Will" and it's a real-time portrayal of the events; the one with the rest of the conversation is Sabo's account to Zoro, Robin and Franky and it's from later on in One Piece episode 738 "The Brothers' Bond - The Untold Story Behind Luffy and Sabo's Reunion".
For the most part this is consistent with the recount of the same meeting in manga chapters 731 and 794, although in chapter 731 the conversation is seen from Bartolomeo's point of vew, who can't hear it. So we may say that the dialogue in episode 663 is an addition to the manga.
Both episodes are available in the current commercial outlets.
